# Why can I compile with this illegal C statement without any error?

Tags: c, arrays

I came across this line in my studies:

> It's illegal for an array initializer to be completely empty. So we have to put a single 0 inside the braces.

But when I compile and run a completely empty array with nothing inside only braces like `int a[]= {};` it compiles and runs fine.

Comment: This seems more like undefined behavior than anything else. Definitely not a standard way of doing things.

Comment: Possibly a compiler specific extension.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers can extend the language. Some use their extensions by default, but they usually allow you to specify a particular standard. In GCC you can do that with the `-std=XXX` argument. For instance, `-std=c17` forces the compiler to adhere to the C 2017 standard.

However, there are some things in the standard that the compilers will ignore even if you issue a `-std` flag. It's the case with your particular example. Both GCC and clang will refuse to complain about empty initializers unless you have a `-pedantic` flag. I'll give an example.

Program:

```
int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {};
    return arr[0];  // this would be invalid even if the above was ok
}
```

Compiling:

```
gcc t.c -std=c17 -pedantic
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:3:14: warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]
    3 |  int arr[] = {};
      |              ^
t.c:3:6: error: zero or negative size array ‘arr’
    3 |  int arr[] = {};
      |      ^~~
```

If you want the pedantic warnings to become errors, you can use `-pedantic-errors` instead.

Comment: `are allowed` is a little bit of overstatement - (in many cases) they are not allowed and C "forbids empty initializer braces". One could argue that a compiler by "extending the language" in such way is no longer a C compiler, as this is no longer valid C language.

Comment: @KamilCuk: The C standard explicitly permits extensions as long as they don't break *strictly conforming* programs. Empty initializer braces are a syntax error, so a conforming C compiler must issue a diagnostic message, but the diagnostic can be a non-fatal warning.

Comment: Well, I reworded the first sentence, but GCC doesn't seem to care. In fact, it refuses to issue an warning even if you specify the standard, `-Wall`, and `-Wextra`. You need `-pedantic`.